# Why isn't my JS button reacting on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to create an interactive Navigation bar following step by step a tutorial video, I did everything (letter by letter) as it was done in the video, but the part when the green indicator should hover on clicking a button (link) is not working. In the video he did insert JS directly into HTML File, didn´t work so I created a JS file and insert the code there, linked it via script under the body, still not working. Any suggestions what may be the problem?

Link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArTVfdHOB-M

Thank you for all answers!

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll(".list");
function activeLink() {
  list.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove("active"));
  this.classList.add("active");
}
list.forEach((item) => item.addEventListener("click", activeLink));
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
}

:root {
  --clr: #222327;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: var(--clr);
}

.navigation {
  width: 400px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 350px;
}

.navigation ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.navigation ul li a .icon {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: var(--clr);
}

.navigation ul li.active a .icon {
  transform: translateY(-32px);
}

.navigation ul li a .text {
  position: absolute;
  color: var(--clr);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(20px);
}

.navigation ul li.active a .text {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

.indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #29fd53;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid var(--clr);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.indicator::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -22px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 1px -10px 0 0 var(--clr);
}

.indicator::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -22px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: -1px -10px 0 0 var(--clr);
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(1).active .indicator {
  transform: translateX(calc(70px * 0));
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(2).active .indicator {
  transform: translateX(calc(70px * 1));
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(3).active .indicator {
  transform: translateX(calc(70px * 2));
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(4).active .indicator {
  transform: translateX(calc(70px * 3));
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(5).active .indicator {
  transform: translateX(calc(70px * 4));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Interactive Navbar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li class="list active">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon></span>
            <span class="text">Home</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon"
              ><ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon
            ></span>
            <span class="text">Profile</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon"
              ><ion-icon name="chatbubble-outline"></ion-icon
            ></span>
            <span class="text">Message</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon"
              ><ion-icon name="camera-outline"></ion-icon
            ></span>
            <span class="text">Photos</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon"
              ><ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon
            ></span>
            <span class="text">Setting</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <div class="indicator"></div>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="module" src="indicator.js"></script>

    <script
      type="module"
      src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      nomodule
      src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have any code here that would move the green indicator. I'm not inclined to go watch a video, so you may have to go back and see what's moving it.

Comment: Please put your code through a validator - it is not totally legal HTML (div as a child of ul not allowed). Once that is sorted out go back to the video and find out what code actually moves the indicator, there is nothing that seems to do that in what you have shown.

Comment: Right. I was just coming back to say that. You'll need to move the indicator outside the list and use a div as the container for both to have valid HTML.

Comment: @AHaworth The indicator is moved by `transform` CSS styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change from `.navigation ul li:nth-child(1).active .indicator` to `.navigation ul li:nth-child(1).active ~ .indicator` for all children.

Notice `~` symbol. To understand `>`, `+` & `~` [read this article.](https://techbrij.com/css-selector-adjacent-child-sibling)

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll(".list");
function activeLink() {
  list.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove("active"));
  this.classList.add("active");
}
list.forEach((item) => item.addEventListener("click", activeLink));
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
}

:root {
  --clr: #222327;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: var(--clr);
}

.navigation {
  width: 400px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 350px;
}

.navigation ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.navigation ul li a .icon {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: var(--clr);
}

.navigation ul li.active a .icon {
  transform: translateY(-32px);
}

.navigation ul li a .text {
  position: absolute;
  color: var(--clr);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(20px);
}

.navigation ul li.active a .text {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

.indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #29fd53;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid var(--clr);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.indicator::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -22px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 1px -10px 0 0 var(--clr);
}

.indicator::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -22px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: -1px -10px 0 0 var(--clr);
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(1).active ~ .indicator {
  transform: translateX(calc(70px * 0));
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(2).active ~ .indicator {
  transform: translateX(calc(70px * 1));
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(3).active ~ .indicator {
  transform: translateX(calc(70px * 2));
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(4).active ~ .indicator {
  transform: translateX(calc(70px * 3));
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(5).active ~ .indicator {
  transform: translateX(calc(70px * 4));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Interactive Navbar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li class="list active">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon></span>
            <span class="text">Home</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon"
              ><ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon
            ></span>
            <span class="text">Profile</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon"
              ><ion-icon name="chatbubble-outline"></ion-icon
            ></span>
            <span class="text">Message</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon"
              ><ion-icon name="camera-outline"></ion-icon
            ></span>
            <span class="text">Photos</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon"
              ><ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon
            ></span>
            <span class="text">Setting</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <div class="indicator"></div>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="module" src="indicator.js"></script>

    <script
      type="module"
      src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      nomodule
      src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To be fair to the OP, the `~` is not easy to see unless you view the video in full screen on a large monitor. The contrast is not very high there.